# stop marquee on mouseover and play on mouseout

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the conventional marquee html tag in my site:

```
<marquee direction="left"><div id="logo-scroll">
    <ul id="clients-logos">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/alcatel.jpg" alt="Alcatel" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abs</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div></marquee>
```

how can i pause marquee through jquery on mouseover and mouseout events keeping in mind that i want to work with marquee tag not jquery script.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `start` and `stop` methods:

```
$("marquee").hover(function () { 
    this.stop();
}, function () {
    this.start();
});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWQqc/**

Just noticed your last line — jQuery provides the `mouseenter` event to non-IE browsers here, making life much easier.  You should keep your JavaScript separate from your HTML because it's much easier to maintain.

Comment: This [works perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/ZWQqc/1/) with `<blink>` as well . Nice job.

Comment: I am also using EasySlider on the same page. When easyslider changes images, marquee gets lag effecting both easyslider images and also marquee animation in IE8, FF4 is working perfect. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: @booota: IE 8 and lower had a very slow JavaScript implementation.  Script execution and rendering share the same thread, so whilst any script is running elements in the page cannot refresh.  My guess is that EasySlider is being a little too intensive and slowing down your page rendering.  If that's the case, you don't have any options other than adjusting or not using EasySlider.

Comment: Can you suggest any better jquery image slider?

Comment: @booota: I'm not really that familiar with jQuery plugins, sorry :)

Comment: By the way, you'll see a quirk where if you put an ID on your marquee like "test" and address it like `$('#test').stop();`, it won't stop. Instead, you have to address it like `$('#test')[0].stop();` [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWQqc/531/)