# How can i stop javascript (marquee) on hover?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to stop the text from moving when i hover it, and then restart when m not hovering.

This is the javascript i use to make the text move.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scrollingtext').bind('marquee', function() {
        var ob = $(this);
        var tw = ob.width();
        var ww = ob.parent().width();
        ob.css({ right: -tw });
        ob.animate({ right: ww }, 30000, 'linear', function() {
            ob.trigger('marquee');
        });
    }).trigger('marquee');
});
```

This is for the text.

```
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="scrollingtext">
        Moving text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin? there is no event in jquery called marqee

Comment: @Kld honestly, im not sure. i never used java really and after i was told to not use the html marquee tag i stumbled upon this code which works.

but i am linking to <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop marquee on mouseover and play on mouseout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160092/stop-marquee-on-mouseover-and-play-on-mouseout)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6160106/3233827

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 not able to get it to work, but heres how mine works now. just need the stop start function http://jsfiddle.net/59r7a2ka/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop an animation with the `stop()` function. However, the animation is then fully stopped and needs to be recreated afterwards. To animate the element again, you need a smaller amount of time (because the element has done already a certain path). So, you need to calculate the amount of milliseconds to finish the animation in the same speed. The `hover()` function allows you to react on mouse over and mouse out events. I didn't rename your variables, but I suggest you to use meaningful variable names. `ob`, `ww` and `tw` is not meaningful and therefore not maintainable. Of course, my code snippet could be improved according to the DRY concept: it is however just a prove of concept. I'm also not sure, why you are working with events here. You could refactor your code and not use a `marquee` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ob = $('.scrollingtext');
    var speed = 10000;

    ob.bind('marquee', function() {
        var tw = ob.width();
        var ww = ob.parent().width();
        ob.css({ right: -tw });
        ob.animate({ right: ww }, speed, 'linear', function() {
            ob.trigger('marquee');
        });
    }).trigger('marquee');

    ob.hover(function() {
        ob.stop();
    }, function() {
        var tw = ob.width();
        var ww = ob.parent().width();
        var cur = parseInt(ob.css('right'), 10);
        var speedDecrease = 1 - ((cur + tw) / (ww + tw));
        ob.animate({ right: ww }, speedDecrease * speed, 'linear', function() {
            ob.trigger('marquee');
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59r7a2ka/2/